# 2 Categories using same template but one has a problem?

Tags: categories, templates

There are only [two links](http://playfulsstudio.com/)  at the top. Sims4 and Sims3. The Sims 4 page is not lining up the posts correctly but The Sims 3 page is. They both use the same template.

Why?

Comment: I hate to request again but, Anyone?

Comment: It seems this is a css issue which is off topic here and not relvant to Wordpress. My guess is also as good as yours with the info given. As it currently stands, your question will most probably attract more negative feedback or no feedback at all than positive feedback. Most people tend to ignore questions where you need to visit the site and look for the issue

Comment: My apologies, I thought the opposite actually. That not including the website would be worse. Technically most questions here are Php related and not WP either..I'm just looking for some coding help. Not to start a argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question as mentioned in the comments is not related to wordpress by any means.

But anywho

remove the float on your #portfolio-item and add some flex like its 2015.

```
#contentportfolio {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

People still play sims?

Comment: *People still play sims?*. Hahaha, apparently they do

Comment: @PieterGoosen I only answered this because of you :) I'm new to this subsection but it seems like every question is begging for negative feedback.

Comment: Poor quality or blatant off topic questions do attract negative feedback on any of the SE sites. On a site like stackoverflow.com for instance, due to its huge member base, you really get punished hard for these type of questions, and it is not rare to see questions with 10 plus downvotes. Each stack is alo quite specific in what type ofquestions is handled on the stack. There are policies which one should read and stick to. I do make users attend to this, try to help them to move the question to the correct stack or improve the quality of their question.

Comment: You are truly doing the community a favor much appreciated. My patience does not run deep for failure to read or simply use google.

Comment: I have read and I have used google. I've been coding for a long time but that does not make it any easier sometimes when things like this elude me. I was just asking for help or a quick eye seeing where I'm going wrong. Tbh I thought it was a PhP issue but regardless I just needed another pair of eyes. Thank you for answering the question. You can see I am new here and I can also see there is not much tolerance for beginner help. Since you answered my question I will answer someone else's "blatant off topic question" in that yes, The Sims 4 was just released last year and doing well.

Comment: @EmpFX I'm not trying to be rude by any means, I'm glad I was able to help you out and happy to hear that Sims 4 is doing well.